# Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to run this code: (code shortened to keep the post short)

```
// Generate a random capital letter
char key = (char)(_random.Next(24) + 65);

// 50% make it lowercase
if (_random.Next(2) == 0)
{
    key = Char.ToLower(key);
}

SendKeys.SendWait(key.ToString());
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully
  at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendInput(Byte[] oldKeyboardState, Queue previousEvents)
  at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(String keys, Control control, Boolean wait)
  at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(String keys)
  at DrunkPC.Program.DrunkKeyboardThread() in c:\Users\SPC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DrunkPC\Program.cs:line 91
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Line 91 is:

```
SendKeys.SendWait(key.toString());
```

Comment: What is the `key` value?

Comment: I cast a `random` variable between 65-90 to a `char` variable in the first line of code, which picks out a random capital letter. Then the `if()` statement randomly makes it a lower case letter.
This is all inside an infinite loop, which is inside a thread.

Comment: I meant what is the `key` value when exception happened. Does exception always happen?

Comment: Yes, it always happens.